# How can I change the database schema using a Statement.execute() in Java ( and SQL Server)?

Tags: java, sql-server

I need to execute a SQL Server system stored procedure, programmatically, and since it executes in the current schema, I need to change it on the fly.

Like this

Statement st = connection.createStatement();
st.execute("EXEC SP_ADDUSER ' ', ' '");

But SP_ADDUSER only executes on the current schema set for the connection, so if I wanted to create users in various schemas, I'd need to change it, and that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to change which database a connection points to.

You'll probably need to create a separate DataSource/Connection for each database (schema).

Comment: There is the possibility of using the USE statement in a batch as well as simply using the fully qualified object name (although sp_adduser doesn't physically exist in the DB, it will be searched for in master and used "virtually").

Answer (score 0):

`EXEC <DatabaseName>..sp_adduser` can be run from a connection to any database (even `master`, say).  The connection will not be affected.

For instance, the following appears to work fine on my system:

```
USE master
EXEC sp_addlogin 'test1'
EXEC SandBox..sp_adduser 'test1'
```

The same things works fine through the client.  Is your client connection altering your SQL?

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestUse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE master; EXEC sp_addlogin 'test1'; EXEC SandBox..sp_adduser 'test1'", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works....but it does not seem to create the user in the correct database, since the SP creates the user in the current database. Since I need to be able to do it in databases other than master, it is not working...."USE master" throws a SQLException for wrong syntax

Comment: The batch I gave works in SQL Server 2005, creating a login and a user in the SandBox database.  If you are just sending a single line, you only need the last line.

Comment: Even though in my batch, the current database is master.  I used that to specifically show that the current database matters not if you use a fully qualified object name.

Comment: Well, it happens that I was making a mistake in the query, so that was causing the SQLException... USE <databaseName> is working fine...as is EXEC <databaseName>..sp_adduser. Thanks for the help

Comment: Note, the standard way of calling a stored procedure in JDBC is with a command like "{call sp_name('spanner')}".

Comment: @Tom - Does JDBC translate the SQL before it reaches the server?  Does it do any rewriting of full-qualified object names or the USE statement?